# Custom logging class python scope

Tags: python, scope

The following dev enviroment is to be considered.

Small number of python modules, each contanining one or more classes. A main module, that calls those classes. A custom logging module called `logger` with a class called `Logger`. Assume that I call the main execution class with a logging level of `debug`. How may I make this sufficient to be that log level inherited to every other call including the rest of the classes, methods in those classes, functions in the main module and so forth...

The `Logger` objects are called like `log=Logger(0)` for example (logging level is an int, to use the same syntax that we use in other scripts (shell scripts, not python).

My final picture is to have the code filled with `log.log_debug('debug message')` and `log.log_error('error message')` but only actually printing a message when the right `log_level` is choosen. And if possible just one

`from logger import Logger`

call within the main module.

Thanks for your time.

==================================

Edit

In the main execution module there is a `main()` function in which a `parser.parse_args()` object is returned with an argument `--log_level` to globally define (at least is my intention) the `log_level`. There is a default `log_level` handling (i.e, it is always defined)

I will try to mock a minimum example

```
import argparse
from logfile from Logfile
from logger import Logger


def argument_parser():

    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()

    stuff

    return parser.parse_args()

def log_file_stuff():

    log_file=Logfile()
    log_file.methods() [*]

def main():

    args=argument_parser()
    # Here log_level is defined with args.log_level
    global log
    log=log(log_level)
    log_file_stuff()

main()
```

[*] One of those methods may call a `Logger` object, **which I want to be exactly the same as the one defined in the `main()` function** the question is **how may I achieve this?** without a log return and argument waterfall

Comment: What have you been tried so far?

Comment: In the main execution module there is a `main()` function in wich a `parser.parse_args()` object is returned with an argument `--log_level` to globally define (at least is my intention) the `log_level`. There is a default log_level handling (i.e, it is always defined) so I write 

`global log`

`some log_level handling`

`log=log(foo)`

if I import some other modules do those modules inherit that `log` object with the user defined `log_level` with that arg parser?

Comment: @Jorge could you please edit your question to include all of the appropriate information and an actual question? As it stands, it is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to answer my own question... I actually implemented a cross module variable dictionary to use it as settings. Those settings have the `log_level` variable son only with

```
from main import settings
from logger import Logger

log=Logger(settings['log_level'])
```

then I have my custom logging class with the user input `log_level`. Of course `settings` is constructed with `argparse`, mainly as `vars(args)` following the notation in the question.